# Choose A as output of merging in KDiff3

Tags: file, merge, compare, kdiff3

Currently I've got stuck with merging files in KDiff. Let's say I have file A and B. A is in the left and B in the right. And now I want to merge file B to A, but when I click **Merge Current File** button, it shows merge editor with B file as an output of merging. How can I choose A as an output file?

Answer (score 3):

From version KDiff3-0.9.89 you can go back to "File" "Open" in the menu and choose to explicitly enter an output file in the "Output (optional)" field, or use one of the choices from the "Swap/Copy Names" control e.g. "Copy B->Output" for your example.

Answer (score 1):

In case you wanted to integrate KDiff3 with Sourcetree to be the external merge tools:

Go to Sourcetree → *Preferences* → *Diff* → *External Diff/Merge*

Merge tool: custom

Merge command: /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3 (or the path to install kdiff3 in Windows)

Arguments: "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" -o "$MERGED"